# Textfield is not allowing me to enter characters on keypress in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a form that when I enter characters by keypress all other browsers it allows the user to do so. But when I use Firefox it doesn't allow the user to enter characters by key press but allows the user to copy and paste. Here is my script below:

```
<script language="javascript">
function aaa(){
            document.getElementById('txtwebref').style.color = 'black';
}
</script>

<input name="txtwebref" type="text" id="txtwebref" size="50" value="Insert reference number" style="width:350px; height:50px; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:15px; text-align:center;color:#CCC; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:24px;" onkeypress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;" onfocus="blank(this);" onblur="unblank(this)" onclick="aaa();"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.event` is not standard JavaScript.

Too do it "the DOM way", assign a function to the `onkeypress` attribute. It's first parameter will be an Event object.

Like so:

```
<input name="txtwebref" type="text" id="txtwebref" size="50" value="Insert reference number" style="width:350px; height:50px; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:15px; text-align:center;color:#CCC; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:24px;" onfocus="blank(this);" onblur="unblank(this)" onclick="aaa();"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('txtwebref').onkeypress = function checkMe(ev) {
        return !isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode) );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
onkeypress="return !isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.charCode))"
```